# PSQL select comma delimited results into join

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

How would you go about returning the key_results, based on the key_id's listed in this comma delimited key_list?

```
SELECT key_list FROM some.place where key_number=1234;
   key_list
----------------
{32,35,58,63,89}

SELECT key_id, key_result FROM some.otherplace;
   key_id   |   key_result
--------------------------
32   |   frisbee
33   |   duckhunt
34   |   hairplugs
35   |   sparkplugs
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your string is a valid PostgreSQL array literal, you can use it as input to `= ANY` with a cast to `integer[]`:

```
SELECT o.key_id, o.key_result 
FROM some.otherplace o
INNER JOIN some.place p ON (o.key_id = ANY (key_list::integer[]))
```

Really though ... this is *bad schema design*. For why, see [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788). At minimum you should store an actual array.

Other useful tools when dealing with comma-separated values are `string_to_array`, `unnest`, and `regexp_split_to_table`.

Comment: This only solves half the problem.  You should put the query in with the `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed, posted before thinking properly, -ENOCOFFEE